# Does django_celery_beat support crontab schedules with multiple minutes/hours?

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I am using `django-celery` (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery/) to store celery beat (Periodic Task) schedules in the DB. But it doesn't support celery beyond version 3.1.25. I want to move to celery 4.1.0 and so I was looking at moving to `django-celery-beat` (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django_celery_beat) for db based schedules.

I was able to successfully migrate the table structures along with data. However, I see that django-celery-beat does not support crontab schedules with multiple minutes and hours which djcelery supported.

For example, consider this crontab schedule - `15,30,45 0,1 * * *`

The task will run everyday at 12:15, 12:30, 12:45, 1:15, 1:30, 1:45. This used to work in django-celery. But in django-celery-beat, it only seems to execute at 12:15 (first instance).

Old setup - `Django==1.10, celery==3.1.24, django-celery==3.1.17`

New setup - `Django==1.11.7, celery==4.1.0, django-celery-beat==1.1.0`

Can anyone confirm whether or not support for such crontab schedules has been dropped in django-celery-beat? If it is supposed to work, is it an issue with celery or django-celery-beat?

Thanks

Comment: Hmm... When you pull them from DB, do you have these in the list or what? And do you use [get_or_create](http://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#example-creating-crontab-based-periodic-task)?

Comment: @mutantkeyboard These are existing schedules in the db that were created using `django-celery`. I also tried creating new ones but not with get_or_create. I directly created a `CrontabSchedule` object and saved it. Does it make a difference if I don't use get_or_create?

Comment: So I assume you have something like 
`app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    # Executes every Monday morning at 7:30 a.m.
    'first-task': {
        'task': 'tasks.add',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=7, minute=30, day_of_week=1),
        'args': (16, 16),
    },
 'second-task': {
        'task': 'tasks.add',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=12, minute=30, day_of_week=1),
        'args': (16, 16),
    }
}` which should be a collection of dictionaries for each task.

Comment: @mutantkeyboard  No. Why would that be needed if I'm storing schedules in the DB?

Comment: @ksrini are you running celery beat with scheduler class selected in command?

Comment: @iklinac Yes. I am running beat with `-S django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm *exactly* how you specified the list values to the database?

I've found that lists like this seems to work: '5,10,15'. For example, I have one schedule that looks like this:

> 0,4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,40,44,48,52,56 * * * 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 (m/h/d/dM/MY)

This is with django-celery-beat==1.1.0, celery==4.1.0 and Django==2.0.1. To be precise, I constructed the call as follows from a celery.schedule.crontab object called `schedule` like this:

```
crontab = {}
for attr in ['minute', 'hour', 'day_of_week', 'day_of_month', 'month_of_year']:
    crontab[attr] = str(list(getattr(schedule, attr)))[1:-1]
self.object.schedule = CrontabSchedule.objects.create(**crontab)
```

I am however about to file a bug because the database field used to store the day-of-month is 64 chars long, which is too short for the worst case scenario of '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31' which is 83 chars without the spaces or 113 with them.

Comment: The bug mentioned is filed as [#122](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat/issues/122).

Comment: I did not use brackets for the lists. It used to work without brackets in djcelery. Hence the question.

Comment: I understand. And I just reviewed the unit tests, and AFAICS, comma separated lists without the brackets should work as well. For example, see [the tests around](https://github.com/ShaheedHaque/django-celery-beat/blob/2074b42a2cbc52e25f6318d7f360f755e8fc87f7/t/unit/test_schedulers.py#L411). That's why I asked you to show exactly how you were calling the code. Without seeing that it is hard to guess at what your problem is.

Comment: On further testing, the brackets DO NOT work (don't ask why I thought they did), but lists definitely do, with the versions I mentioned. I am updating my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I looked at the link to the tests you had mentioned. The test `test_CrontabSchedule_schedule` seems to indicate that comma separated values should work. Isn't it?